# Cordova Plugin - Add third party sdk

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am trying to create the plugin for the following sdk - https://ktplayhelp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/221071888-Android

In the setup project configuration point it is telling to setup the sdk by importing module in Android studio and add the dependency in our application's build.gradle file.

Can anyone please help and tell me how can I import the Android native module in Cordova without using Android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't modify cordovas `.gradle` file you have to add your own and reference it in your `plugin.xml` you can do that like this:

```
<framework src="src/android/*.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

This will allow you to do things like compiling an external module. To make this actually work you will have to create an `.aar` library out of the project you want to integrate.

The resulting gradle-extension will look something like this:

```
repositories {    
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'KTplay', ext:'aar')
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

This assumes that you have put your `.aar` library in a subdirectory of your plugin named `libs`. Whats left to do is to ensure that the library actually gets copied during the build process, this is why we have to add it as a resource file in `plugin.xml`:

```
<resource-file src="libs/KTplay.aar" target="libs/KTplay.aar" />
```

Comment: Thank you David, it worked perfectly. I created the aar file for the module using Android Studio and then use the above gradle file and referenced in plugin.xml.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help you out!