# Creating a cordova plugin for onyx beacon SDK

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to expose an android SDK named onyx beacon methods by creating a cordova plugin. I'm new to creating a cordova plugin.

Can someone please help me how to start with this. I have downloaded the SDK folder i just have an .aar file (i.e. OnyxBeaconLibrary-release.aar). The SDK for which i'm trying to write a cordova plugin is "Onyx Beacon SDK v2.5.2"

Please share me any samples that is available on internet to expose the SDK methods using a cordova plugin. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46200988/6184203).