# How to add third party SDK properly to Cordova plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I am creating a custom Cordova plugin and am currently trying to import it into my ionic Cordova project. However, it always says me that the .aar file cannot be found during compilation. I have followed this answer: [Cordova Plugin - Add third party sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199606/cordova-plugin-add-third-party-sdk)

This is my folder structure for the plugin:

```
plugin
|--libs
|--src
|----ios
|----android
|------libs
|------sdk.gradle
|--www
|--package.json
|--plugin.xml
```

This is my `plugin.xml`:

```
<platform name="android">
        <framework src="src/android/sdk.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />    
            <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
                <feature name="MationPlugin">
                    <param name="android-package" value="cordova.plugin.custom.MationPlugin" />
                </feature>
            </config-file>
            <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml"></config-file>
            <source-file src="src/android/MationPlugin.java" target-dir="src/cordova/plugin/custom/MationPlugin" />
            <resource-file src="src/android/libs/library.aar" target="src/android/libs/library.aar" />
</platform>
```

This my `sdk.gradle`:

```
repositories {    
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'library', ext:'aar')
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
```

This is the error message I get after running `ionic cordova run android` in the plugin test app.

```
E:\wamp64\www\fyp\test\pluginTestApp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find :library:.
  Required by:
      project :app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <source-file src="src/android/libs/library.aar" target-dir="libs" />
```

This works for me.
basically for cordova plug, every single java file or library used in the plugin needs to be indicated as above in plugin.xml.
my previous plugin.xml did not work due to `target` instead of `target-dir`

Comment: Consider adding an explanation as to how and why your code solves the problem.